# Render svelte component inside ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid, svelte

Does anyone have an example of how to render a svelte component inside of ag grid?  Similar to how you can render an angularjs or react component inside of ag-grid.

Comment: ugh I wish somebody had an answer to this question

Comment: @GeorgK. check my answer

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to @ben-sewards answer, I've come up with a factory function to make it easier for me to embed random components.

```js
    /**
     * Base class for embedding a svelte component within an AGGrid call.
     * See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72608215
     */
    import type {
      ICellRendererComp,
      ICellRendererParams
    } from "ag-grid-community";

    /**
     * Class for defining a cell renderer.
     * If you don't need to define a separate class you could use cellRendererFactory 
     * to create a component with the column definitions.
     */
    export abstract class AbstractCellRenderer implements ICellRendererComp {

      eGui: any
      protected value: any

      constructor(parentElement = "span") {
        // create empty span (or other element) to place svelte component in
        this.eGui = document.createElement(parentElement);
      }

      init(params: ICellRendererParams) {
        this.value = params.value;
        this.createComponent(params);
      }

      getGui() {
        return this.eGui;
      }

      refresh(params: ICellRendererParams) {
        this.value = params.value;
        this.eGui.innerHTML = '';

        return true;
      }

      /**
       * Define and create the svelte component to use in the cell
       * @example
       * // This is all you need to do within this method: create the component with new, specify the target
       * // is the class, and pass in props via the params.
       * new CampusIcon({
       *    target: this.eGui,
       *    props: {
       *        color: params.data?.color,
       *        name: params.data?.name
       * }
       * @param params params for rendering the call, including the value for the cell
       */
      abstract createComponent(params: ICellRendererParams): void
    }

    /**
     * Creates a cell renderer using the given callback for how to initialise a svelte component.
     * See AbstractCellRenderer.createComponent
     * @param svelteComponent function for how to create the svelte component
     * @returns 
     */
    export function cellRendererFactory(svelteComponent: (cell: AbstractCellRenderer, params: ICellRendererParams) => void) {
      class Renderer extends AbstractCellRenderer {
        createComponent(params: ICellRendererParams < any, any > ): void {
          svelteComponent(this, params)
        }
      }
      return Renderer;
    }
```

And then for the column defs, use it like this:

```js
    import CampusIcon from '$lib/components/campus/CampusIcon.svelte';


    const columnDefs = [
        {
            field: 'campusId',
            cellRenderer: cellRendererFactory((c, p) => {
                new CampusIcon({
                    target: c.eGui,
                    props: {
                        color: p.data?.color,
                        name: p.data?.name
                    }
                });
            }),
            headerName: 'Campus',
        }
    ]
```

Comment: a wonderful way to pass the cell params to the svelte component, have an upvote!

Comment: Beautiful , thanks

Answer (score 3):

Since there isn't a svelte extension for AG-Grid, you might have to handle this using the Svelte [client-side component API](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-client-side-component-api).

**EDIT: Tested working approach below**

Create CellRenderer

```typescript
import SiteAccountCellButtonSvelte from "./SiteAccountCellButton.svelte";

export class SiteAccountButtonRenderer {
  constructor() {
    // create empty div to place svelte component in
    this.eGui = document.createElement("div");
  }

  init(params: ICellRendererParams) {
    this.value = params.value;

    new SiteAccountCellButtonSvelte({
      target: this.eGui,
      props: {
        // your props here
        siteBalance: params.data,
      },
    });
  }

  getGui() {
    return this.eGui;
  }

  refresh(params) {
    this.value = params.value;
    this.eGui.innerHTML = '';

    return true;
  }
}
```

Configure AG-Grid options

```typescript
const gridOptions: GridOptions = {
  pagination: true,
  paginationPageSize: 15,
  domLayout: "autoHeight",
  rowHeight: 56,
  defaultColDef: {
    sortable: true,
    unSortIcon: true,
    resizable: true,
    flex: 1,
    minWidth: 170,
  },
  columnDefs: [
    {
      headerName: "account name",
      field: "accountName",
      filter: true,
      floatingFilter: true,
      cellClass: (_params: CellClassParams) => {
        return "fw-bold";
      },
      cellRenderer: SiteAccountButtonRenderer,
    },
    // more columnDefs here
  ],
};
```

Initialize Grid in Parent Svelte Component

```html
  <script lang="ts">
    import { Grid } from "@ag-grid-community/core";
    import { onMount } from "svelte";
    import type { SiteBalance, SiteBalancesViewModel } from "../../../typings/Payments";
    import { createGridOptions } from "./SiteBalances";
  
    export let vm: SiteBalancesViewModel;
    export let data: SiteBalance[];
  
    let gridEl: HTMLElement;
  
    onMount(async () => {
      const gridOptions = createGridOptions(vm);
      new Grid(gridEl, gridOptions);
      gridOptions.api.setRowData(data);
    });
  </script>
  
  <div style="height: 100%;" bind:this={gridEl} class="ag-theme-alpine" />
```

**Original Answer**

I haven't set this up before, but the general set up might be something like:

1. Create Svelte component with props per usual
2. Set up an ag-grid [Cell Renderer](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/#simple-cell-renderer)
   2a. In the `init` method, make sure the `this.eGui.innerHTML` property is set to an empty div with the CSS selector of the svelte component (`<div class="svelte-widget"></div>`)
   2b. In the same `init` method, initialize the svelte component:

```typescript
import SvelteWidget, { selector as SvelteWidgetSelector } from "./your-path/SvelteWidget.svelte";

class SvelteWidgetRenderer {
    init(params) {
        this.eGui = document.createElement('div');
        this.eGui.classList.add('svelte-widget');

        // initialize svelte widget with client-side component API
        new SvelteWidget({ target: this.eGui, props: { /* your props */ });
    }
}
```

*the svelte widget "selector" is optional because we are attaching the svelte component to the ag-grid DOM element*

Comment: Wow! Thanks! I've created my own grid in the meantime but your answer will be great for future programmers